# table inheritance: TPH, TPT and single table vs taxonomies

Tags: database-design, table, inheritance

according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database) and many others web resources, you can do table inheritance with `Table Per Hierarchy Inheritance`, `Table Per Type Inheritance` or `Single table` (single table for all sub classes).
What about taxonomies? I do not know if "taxonomy" is the right word, I try to explain.

I have 3 entities type:

- Organization (father)

  - Restaurant (child)
  - Hotel (child)

These are the tables I thought:

```
organization_type (id, name) // (ex. "restaurant", "hotel")
organization (id, name, organization_type_id)
organization_taxonomy (id, name) // (ex. "rooms_number", "tables_number")
organization_has_taxonomy (organization_id, organization_taxonomy_id, value)
```

If I need another organization type, I just need to:

1. add record to `organization_type` table
2. add records to `organization_taxonomy` table

Are there some drawbacks in this approach I am not thinking about?

Answer (score 1):

> Are there some drawbacks in this approach I am not thinking about?

Only if it becomes an [EAV anti-pattern](https://cedanet.com.au/antipatterns/eav.php) approach, which will depend on your use cases.

If your database needed to store, manage, and query specific data attributes about the different organizations such as "*select all restaurants with a 5 star rating*" or "*update the price of any hotels with less than 100 rooms and is located in Montana*", etc, then your current design would not be appropriate. As mentioned in the link I provided on the EAV anti-pattern, it would be inefficient and difficult to query, not enforce proper data integrity, and typically isn't scalable.

Your `organization_taxonomy` concerns me a little bit, that it may become the EAV anti-pattern, based on your comments "*// (ex. "rooms_number", "tables_number")*". If you plan to store multiple specific attributes of each `Organization` which you'll need to query off of later on, then you should store them in their own specific tables for that type of `Organization`. I.e. `Hotels` should be a dedicated table vs `Restaurants` being a separate table.